# Load column form parse in to an Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am working on a little app with parse.com. I want to download all objects from a column (Array) called "Firstname". I found some code, but when I log "object" it shows the class completely:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Name"];

[query selectKeys:@[@"Firstname"]];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
     NSLog("%@", objects);
}];
```

**Edit:**

```
 PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Name"];

[query selectKeys:@[@"Firstname"]];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

    self.FirstnameArray = [objects valueForKey:@"Firstname"];

    NSLog(@"%@", self.FirstnameArray);

    [self.myTableView reloadData];
}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A query always returns objects of the class associated with the query. Using `selectKeys` just limits the data that comes back.

You can extract an array of just the values from the returned array with:

```
NSArray *values = [objects valueForKey:@"Firstname"]
```

Comment: Thank you. Now when I am log it, I will become the right objects. But even I set [self.myTableView reloadData] to update my tableview, it will crash

Comment: Probably a different question, what is the array now (strings?) and what's the exception?

Comment: The objects in the column are Strings.

Comment: It works now. It was my mistake. I set the column as an Array instand of a String. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Thats normal, you will get back the whole object - aka a row from that class you are performing the query on. If I recall correct, SelectKey will return any associated object - ie a relation object. So in your case you do not need to use select.